# Setup ISchedulingRule to allow n-Threads at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

I have an existing `ISchedulingRule` that only allows one typ of Thread to be scheduled if the following `ISchedulingRule` is applied to them:

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ISchedulingRule;

    public class Mutex implements ISchedulingRule {

        public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
            return (rule == this);
        }

        public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {       
            return (rule == this);
        }

    }
```

How can I extend this rule to allow n-Threads at a time? I have tried using a static variable to keep track of the running instances count but when I try to do something like this

```
public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
            return instancesCount>4;
        }
```

I get an exception that this is not reflexive. I'm fully aware what reflexive means in a mathematical context but I have a hard time applying that knowledge to scheduling rules. So if you can point me into the right direction, that would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this question after 5 months :(